# create stackbar from two different pandas output

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to parse a csv file using a code like: (I have updated the code at the bottom. Please have a look)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import cm

cmap = cm.get_cmap('tab20')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 4)
#  pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
dataset = pd.read_csv("mwe.csv")
dsc = dataset.columns
print(dataset.value_counts(subset=[dsc[1]]).reset_index(name='count'))
print(dataset.value_counts(subset=[dsc[1], dsc[0]]).reset_index(name='count'))
```

and a sample mwe is:

```
Quartile,KeyArea
Q2,Earth
Q1,Earth
Q1,Fire
,Fire
Q3,Fire
Q1,Space
Q3,Space
Q1,Space
Q4,Space
Q2,Space
,Space
Q2,Air
Q1,Air
Q1,Air
Q1,Air
,Air
Q2,Water 
Q2,Water 
Q1,Water
```

The  output of the code with the data is:

```
#Total
 KeyArea  count
0     Air      5
1   Space      5
2    Fire      3
3  Water       3
4   Earth      2

#Keyarea split by Q1..Q4.
   KeyArea Quartile  count
0      Air       Q1      3
1    Space       Q1      2
2   Water        Q2      2
3      Air       Q2      1
4    Earth       Q1      1
5    Earth       Q2      1
6     Fire       Q1      1
7     Fire       Q3      1
8    Space       Q2      1
9    Space       Q3      1
10   Space       Q4      1
11  Water        Q1      1
```

Now, I am trying to get a stack bar plot with something like:

```
ax.bar(labels, q1, label='Q1')
ax.bar(labels, q2, bottom=q1, label='Q2')
ax.bar(labels, extra, bottom=q1 + q2, label='Others', color='C3')
```

i.e. for each keyarea, stack will be like keyarea in q1, keyarea in q2, total keyarea-keyarea in q1+q2.

How I can do that?

Update:

```
I have updated the code with:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import cm

cmap = cm.get_cmap('tab20')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 4)
#  pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
dataset = pd.read_csv("mwe.csv")
dsc = dataset.columns
dataset[dsc[1]].fillna("None", inplace=True)
print(dict(dataset.value_counts(subset=[dsc[0], dsc[1]]).sort_index()))
```

Which is giving the output:

```
{('Air', 'Q1'): 3, ('Air', 'Q2'): 1, ('Earth', 'Q1'): 1, ('Earth', 'Q2'): 1, ('Fire', ' Q1'): 1, ('Fire', 'Q3'): 1, ('Space', 'Q1'): 2, ('Space', 'Q2'): 1, ('Space', 'Q3'): 1, ('Space', 'Q4'): 1, ('Water', 'Q1'): 1, ('Water', 'Q2'): 2}
```

Now, I have to create a stack, say for Space. I need first stack for Q1, i.e. for `('Space', 'Q1'):2`, second for (Space,Q2), and third with `None+Q3+Q4`.

Kindly help

NB:This is a restatement of the question [create stackbar from tw different pandas output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68780008/create-stackbar-from-tw-different-pandas-output), as I have managed a mwe code and dataset. I will close the question.

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve. Do you simply want a stacked bar chart from the df with Quartile?

Comment: @HenryYik: yes. But, the first output is the total number of Water,Space etc. In 2nd output, it is splitted in Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 and may be empty. So, in the stack, I want stack of 3, with Water from Q1, water from Q2 and Total water -(Water from Q1 and Water from Q2). I can easily plot Water from Q1 and Q2. I dont know, since the total number is in another output, how to get the 3rd stack.

Comment: If its a stacked bar, the bars would stack up to the total amount. why do you need to plot the total water seperately?

Comment: @HenryYik: because, as I said, Stack is from Q1 , Q2, and total. Total is (if you have read the last comment, Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+ nothing), which is not equal to Q1+Q2, as described in the 3rd sentence of my previous comment.

Comment: So, for example, take stack of "Space" . Here, Q1=2, Q2=Q3=Q4=none=1. So, bottom stack should be of height 2 for Q1, middle is of height 1 for Q2, and for third stack is from total - (stack of Q1+Q2)=3.

Comment: @HenryYik: I have updated the code. Please have a look, if your time permits

Comment: Doesn't that means you simply want to add up Q3 and Q4 as an extra column? The answer posted already `pivot` the data, so just add Q3 and Q4 and plot it.

Comment: @HenryYik: Please try to understand my problem. I dont have much experience in python data. Actually This is the first time I am seeing a dict key as a set of two value. So, forget about adding Q3+Q4+None, I dont know how to stack the (Fire,Q1) value itself.
I am totally lost.

Comment: Please have a look a the [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68782775/16343464). I showed two examples of data. 1. raw quartiles plotted as stacked. 2. same with added "other" to sum up to the values in the first dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your quartile dataset is named `quartiles_df`, you do not need the totals to plot a stacked bar, pandas can do it for you. You need to pivot your data first:

```
quartiles_df.pivot(*quartiles_df).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Below are a few graphical outputs:

```
pivoted_df = (quartiles_df.pivot(index='KeyArea',
                                 columns='Quartile',
                                 values='count')
              )
pivoted_df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image: stacked bars]

Complement to total (`total_df`):

```
(pivoted_df.assign(other=total_df.set_index('KeyArea')['count']-pivoted_df.sum(axis=1))
           .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

[image: complement to total]

Comment: can you please also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68789629/pandas-plot-split-long-xtickslabels, if your time permits?

Comment: It looks like you already have a nice answer there ;)